# How to create Android Icon Pack (.apk)

Tags: android-studio, android-icons

I want to create custom icons for various applications for my OnePlus 8 Pro smartphone (running on Android 11 - Oxygen OS 11). I have created few vector images as icons for few different applications. The question is how to pack few icons in a single icon pack, so that I can install it on my smartphone and then apply them with my default OnePlus launcher.

I have no experience in programming, only in graphics.

I generated from each vector source icon several png-files with different sizes: 192x192, 144x144, 96x96, 72x72, 48x48, 36x36 pixels and put them into individual folders "mipmap-xxxhdpi", "mipmap-xxhdpi", "mipmap-xhdpi" and so on. And placed all these folders into "res" folder.
So as a result I have, for example, 5 images (for 5 applications) in each "mipmap-" folder. But I have no understanding how to pack these folders into final .apk file.

As far as I understand, it could be done by means of Android Studio IDE. If so, would appreciate some step-by-step instructions.